# Sharepoint Sandbox solution - Updating Sitepages/Home.aspx on webprovisioned event, Occasional conflict error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sandbox

As part of a sandbox solution I am creating, I have a web provisioned event receiver that does the following:

- Updates the new sites branding to match the root site
- Updates the default sitepages/home.aspx (if it exists)
- Deletes the OOTB default.aspx (if the site has a sitepages/home)

This all seems to work ‘most’ of the time, but occasionally when creating a sub site the following error message appears:

> Error - The file SitePages/Home.aspx has been modified by xxx@xxx on 02 Oct 2012 08:51:36 -0700.

It doesn’t happen all the time which makes it really strange to understand and debug.  It almost appears to happen if you create a site to quick after creating another?

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening. It is worth noting that I am on SharePoint Online so can not check the correlation ID.

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {

        // Get and set child and top sites
        SPWeb childSite = properties.Web;
        SPWeb topSite = childSite.Site.RootWeb;

        // Apply branding from top site to childsite
        childSite.MasterUrl = topSite.MasterUrl;
        childSite.CustomMasterUrl = topSite.CustomMasterUrl;
        childSite.AlternateCssUrl = topSite.AlternateCssUrl;
        childSite.SiteLogoUrl = topSite.SiteLogoUrl;
        childSite.Update();


        // Construct HTML for new home.aspx page
        string content = "Test Content";


        // Check if the newsite has a sitepages library and home.aspx
        SPFile oFile = childSite.GetFile("Sitepages/Home.aspx");
        if (oFile.Exists)
        {
            // replace page content with new html
            oFile.Item["WikiField"] = content;

            // Update
            oFile.Item.Update();

            // Delete old Default page. 
            SPFile oDefault = childSite.GetFile("default.aspx");
            if (oDefault.Exists) 
            {
                oDefault.Delete();
            }
            oDefault.Update();
        }

    }
```